# Asp net BoilerPlate CreateMultiLingualMap With ProjectTo

Tags: asp.net, automapper, multilingual, aspnetboilerplate, projectto

I am using asp.net boilerplate multilingual mapper but it it does not access the translations when I use AutoMapper Extension Project To it fails to reach translations to get the name so it return null

If I tried Manual Include it works so fine

```
 var category = await BaseRepository.GetAll()
                                    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                                    .Include(x=>x.Translations)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

 var response = category.MapToType<AdminCategoryDto>();
```

and returns

```
{
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Cat1"
 }
```

but this code

```
var response = await BaseRepository.GetAll()
                                    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                                    .ProjectTo<AdminCategoryDto>(ConfigurationProvider)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

returns this

```
 {
     "id": 16,
     "name": null
 }
```

and this is my mapper

`config.CreateMultiLingualMap<Category,long,CategoryTranslation,long, AdminCategoryDto>(MultiLingualMapContext)`